# Aiogram, problem with edit_media. Error:"aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: MEDIA_EMPTY"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@router.message(Command("start"))
async def start_handler(msg:Message):

    structural.adapter.url_to_square(url=constans.BASE)

    request = FSInputFile("request.png")
    await msg.answer_photo(request, reply_markup=menu)
```

```
@router.callback_query()
async def my_handler(query: CallbackQuery):   
    request1 = InputMediaPhoto(media="request1.png")
    await query.message.edit_media(media = request1, reply_markup = menu)
```

This my code, it purpouse edit first message, which photo, by clicking by inline keyboar . But there is error: "aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: MEDIA_EMPTY"

How can I fix this?